# Python UI made with Qt Creator isn't showing any window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I made a ui for my python app in Qt Creator and converted it from a .ui to a .py using `pyuic5 mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py` which worked, but when i run mainwindow.py no window shows up.  Im on macOS, but I also tried it on my windows pc and it didn't work there either.  Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(731, 466)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout_4.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout_4.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.username.setObjectName("username")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.username, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(508, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.password, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(508, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout_3.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_16, 3, 4, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_17, 4, 4, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.u6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u6.setObjectName("u6")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u6, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.u1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u1.setObjectName("u1")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_14, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_18, 1, 6, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_12, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.u15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u15.setObjectName("u15")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u15, 4, 5, 1, 1)
        self.u18 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u18.setObjectName("u18")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u18, 2, 7, 1, 1)
        self.u9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u9.setObjectName("u9")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u9, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.u17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u17.setObjectName("u17")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u17, 1, 7, 1, 1)
        self.label_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_22.setObjectName("label_22")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_22, 3, 6, 1, 1)
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_20, 2, 6, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_15, 2, 4, 1, 1)
        self.u10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u10.setObjectName("u10")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u10, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_19, 0, 6, 1, 1)
        self.u19 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u19.setObjectName("u19")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u19, 3, 7, 1, 1)
        self.u14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u14.setObjectName("u14")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u14, 3, 5, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_8, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.u2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u2.setObjectName("u2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_7, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.u20 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u20.setObjectName("u20")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u20, 4, 7, 1, 1)
        self.u5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u5.setObjectName("u5")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.u4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u4.setObjectName("u4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.u13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u13.setObjectName("u13")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u13, 2, 5, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.u11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u11.setObjectName("u11")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u11, 0, 5, 1, 1)
        self.u12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u12.setObjectName("u12")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u12, 1, 5, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.u8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u8.setObjectName("u8")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u8, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.u16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u16.setObjectName("u16")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u16, 0, 7, 1, 1)
        self.u7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u7.setObjectName("u7")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u7, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_21, 4, 6, 1, 1)
        self.u3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.u3.setObjectName("u3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.u3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.run = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.run.setObjectName("run")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.run, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 731, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "U:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "P:"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "14."))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "15."))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3."))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2."))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9."))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11."))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "12."))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7."))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "17."))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10."))
        self.label_22.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "19."))
        self.label_20.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "18."))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "13."))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "16."))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6."))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5."))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4."))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8."))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1."))
        self.label_21.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "20."))
        self.run.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
```

Comment: are you sure there is no error causing it to crash?

Comment: all that file does is to declare a class. it does not even instanciate that class, let alone a QMainWindow

Comment: @JonasWielicki good point there, didnt even notice that

Answer (score 0):

The `uic` only "compiles" the `.ui` XML files into a class which can be used to re-create the designed UI on a `QMainWindow`. To make use of it, you need a script which uses it. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

import PyQt5.Qt as Qt

import mainwindow


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._ui = mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self._ui.setupUi(self)


app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```